# How to integrate Django authentication with Jinja2 templates properly?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2, django-authentication

I am trying to use authentication and authorisation system provided by Django and as I can see the default built-in views for login/logout expect Django templates, hence I cannot use my Jinja2 `base.html` file to extend them as I have already integrated Jinja2 engine.

I was able to solve this problem by replicating 'base.html' and changing syntax to Django template, but this approach forces me to rely on two same files in different templating languages.

However, now I have other issue, I cannot access the `user` object in Jinja2 template `context`, even though I can do that in Django template.

By saying 'I cannot access':

```
File "/home/dir/workspace/project/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 430, in getattr return getattr(obj, attribute)
UndefinedError: 'user' is undefined
```

My Jinja2 template:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <li>User: {{ user.get_username }}</li>
  <li><a href="{% url 'logout'%}?next={{request.path}}">Logout</a></li>
{% else %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'login'%}?next={{request.path}}">Login</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

My question is, how can I go around this problem? Should I just switch back Django templates, because this becomes more and more messy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the Django template language, you can use `{{ user }}` because the auth context processor is enabled. However [using context processors with Jinja2 is  discouraged](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2).

You have access to `request` in the Jinja2 template context, so you can access `request.user`.

```
Supported in Django 1.10 and 1.11, required in Django 2.0+
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
```

Note that in Django < 1.10, `user.is_authenticated()` is a method so you must call it in the Jinja2 template:

```
Required in Django < 1.10, supported in Django 1.10 and 1.11
{% if request.user.is_authenticated() %}
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks again @Alasdair! I had one more question, so the built-in django-registration uses the templates like login.html/logged_out.html etc., is it possible to extend them with my jinja base.html or should I have a separate django-template base.html?

Comment: You can't extend a Django template with a Jinja template or vice versa. I would try to avoid having base templates for Jinja and Django, it sounds like needless duplication. You might have problems if you try to override the `registration/` templates with Jinja templates, since they are also used by the Django admin which uses Django templates. You could probably customize `django-registration` and the built in authentication views to point to Jinja2 templates.

Answer (score 2):

Alasdair's answer is the best!  So consider this an addendum: if you're converting a lot of DTL templates to Jinja2, and they all extend from a common base, consider putting in the base file something like:

```
{% if user is not defined %}
     {% set user=request.user %}
{% endif %}
```

Then you'll be able to use your prior user variables without a problem.